# Cannot connect to database after installing Nuget Package Microsoft.Asp.Net.Webhelpers

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue with connecting to any of my databases after installing `Microsoft.Asp.Net.Webhelpers`. I have uninstalled it and still having an issue:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
> not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
> correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
> Server/Instance Specified)

My live site uses this database and is up and working. It does the same thing when I use my local machine connection. Does anyone know what this package may have changed in my project to cause this? I appologize if this is not the correct place to put it, I really do not know what code needs to be posted because everything was working fine before installing this package..

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:
I am now showing an error that I need to restore with nuget package manager. Something is missing. It is set to automatically update missing packages but for some reason it doesn't. So I closed the program and will reboot my system and see what happens when I reopen and try to rebuild. I will do a clean first.

UPDATE:
The Problem package appears to be `Microsoft.AspNet.Webpages.data` which is a dependancy of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers. As soon as I install this package I loose database connectivity. I have not found any information on this issue anywhere. It seems strange to me because Microsoft has it under the latest version of .net. Which i am using..

Comment: Look at the following post: [SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance/ba-p/383277). And this might help you to discover the problem too: [New features and functionality in PortQry version 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/portqry-command-line-port-scanner-v2).

Comment: @Saul Wilson-spencer  I do have a prev version but it would take alot of rework to get it to the point of this version.. I just updated all my packages in this. Of course that causes issues as well. If that is the only solution, I guess i will have to do it..

Comment: @jackdaw Thanks but I do not see where this is my case. I have been using this connection string for a long time without error. I did not get the error until I installed the package.

Comment: The error message `SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified` is your case and the referenced posts can help you to discover what is changed in you environment after installing the `Microsoft.Asp.Net.Webhelpers` package. For example, the package installer updated your application file incorrectly etc.